# A text field input with sugestions and with a select option

Tags: android

I am making an android app with a database that stores names. When a user starts typing in a name I want couple of suggestions to pop up so the user can select one. (just like google suggest).

I also wonder if there is a way to keep the suggest function but also have the ability to simply pick from the list (like the select tag in html).

- I would prefer an answer that shows how to accomplish both of the effects.

I will appreciate any suggestions/partial answers as well as code and instructions to make it all happen.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a pop-up object... in that object use a ListView. Then, use a text watcher for your edit text, as you type, populate the listview based on the input from the textwatcher. Then if the list item gets clicked, handle it like you would any other list item.

Comment: You should have made that an answer.